# Parsing table to regex method

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, url

I have this Javascript snippet :

```
var appId = document.URL;
var ele = [];
ele = appId.split('/', 5);
appId = ele[4];
```

which extracts the sub-site name from some urls :

**Example**

- http://www.test.com/france/Admin/Get.aspx  ==> Admin
- www.test.com/france/Gallery ==> Gallery

It works fine, but I need to change the table approach to regex ie I need to get the string just after `france`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to say with the word "table"?

Comment: I  mean an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern `\/france\/(.*?(?=\/)|.*)`

**[Demo regex and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/NX78lg/5/)**

**Upadted** 
All matching with first position

```js
console.log(find("http://www.test.com/france/Admin/Get.aspx"))
console.log(find("www.test.com/france/Gallery"))
console.log(find("test.com/france/Admin-en-france/Get.aspx"))



function find(str){
return /\/france\/(.*?(?=\/)|.*)/g.exec(str)[1]
}
```

Comment: thank you :) But I have for example this url which didn't match with the function http://www.test.com/france/Admin-en-france/Get.aspx. How can I improve your solution?

Comment: @LamloumiAfif see my latest updated answer. I was changed all the matching string in `array` first position